# Deconvolution with fourier transform or characteristic function?

Tags: probability, convolution, fourier-transform, method-of-moments, characteristic-function

Let us consider the following model:

$$Y_j = X_j + \epsilon_j \hspace{15pt} j=1, ..., n$$

Where $Y_j$ is a noisy signal, $\epsilon_j$ is the noise which is independend from the signal $X_j$. We have only i.i.d. samples of $Y_j$ and $\epsilon_j$ and are interested in the distribution of $X_j$. The density $f_{\epsilon}$ is assumed to be unknown.
[Comte and Lacour](http://www.math-info.univ-paris5.fr/~comte/BruitInconnu.pdf) suggest a method based on fourier transform to solve this problem (see section 2.2).

Let's call $\varphi_X(t)$ the characteristic function for $X$ and $f^{*}_X$ the fourier transform of the density $f_X$.

Here is my question:
The main idea in deconvolution is to use the independence assumption for $X$ and $\epsilon$ and then use fourier transform to solve the equation $f^{*}_X = f^{*}_Y/f^{*}_{\epsilon}$. Applying the inverse fourier transform leads to an estimate for $f_X$.

Can I use the characteristic function instead of the fourier transform?
Does this give me any advantages or disadvantages? I assume that both fourier transform or characteristic function could be used but would like to know what other people think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Page 342, of Probability and Measure. P. Billingsley 3rd editon.

The characteristic function in nonprobabilistic contexts is called the *Fourier transform*.

So yes both can be used as they are the same thing.

Comment: Okay this sounds like what I was looking for. My issue is that I can't see from their definition that both characteristic function and fourier transform are the same thing:
fourier transform is defined as $\int \exp(-itx) \cdot f(x) \; dx$ [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)
and the characteristic function $\int \exp(itx) \cdot f(x) \; dx$ [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Definition)
As we can see the definition differ with a minus. Why can we than say that both are the same thing? Is there any proof?

Comment: They are *conceptually* the same thing, this differences of signs is a plague but insignificant conceptually, they contain the same information.

Comment: @Giuseppe There are _two_ square roots of $-1$. If you label one of them as $i$, then the other equals $-i$. But, someone else (e.g. an electrical engineer such as myself) might well label the _other_ square root as $j$ in which case, what you call as $i$ is my $-j$. So, my Fourier transforms are your characteristic functions and vice versa, and yet, my math works in exactly the same way as your math and I can use all your theorems and tables of Fourier transforms as long as I simply replace $i$, wherever I find it, with $j$